# Changing the colour of text when expiry date is nearing the end. C# Mvc 3

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-3

On my html page I want to change the colour of the date when it close to expiring.

```
<div class="account-label">Billing Expiry Date</div>
   @if (Model.BillingCycleID == 1 && (DateTime.Now.AddDays(23) == true))
      {
        <div class="account-field2">@Model.BillingEndDate.ToLongDateString()</div>
      }
   else
      {
         <div class="account-field">@Model.BillingEndDate.ToLongDateString()</div>
      }

@if (Model.BillingCycleID == 2 && (DateTime.Now.AddDays(176) == true))
    {
        <div class="account-field2">@Model.BillingEndDate.ToLongDateString()</div>
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="account-field">@Model.BillingEndDate.ToLongDateString()</div>
    }

    @if (Model.BillingCycleID == 3 && (DateTime.Now.AddDays(328) == true))
    {
        <div class="account-field2">@Model.BillingEndDate.ToLongDateString()</div>
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="account-field">@Model.BillingEndDate.ToLongDateString()</div>
    }
```

Is there a better way of doing this?  I have a billing end date and a billing start date.  Billing cycle is for the certain billing cycle they wish to have be it monthly, 6 month or yearly. Account - field 2 changes it to red and account 1 stays white. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest adding a method to your `Model` that defines whether the `Model` is close to expiring. This will simplify your view and encapsulate the business logic in the `Model`, maintaining the MVC separation of concerns. Something like:

```
@if (Model.IsCloseToExpiring())
{
    <div class="account-field2">@Model.BillingEndDate.ToLongDateString()</div>
}
else
{
    <div class="account-field">@Model.BillingEndDate.ToLongDateString()</div>
}
```

Other things to consider:

- Avoid magic numbers, define the number of days until an account becomes about to expire as `const`. It'll make the code easier to understand and easier to modify in the future, if for example, you want to keep these values in configuration or a database.
- `Model.BillingCycleID` isn't very descriptive, would an `enum` fit you design instead?

e.g.

```
public enum BillingCycle
{
    Monthly,
    Biannually,
    Annually
}
```

Comment: I'll keep these suggestions in mind. This was very helpful. Thanks :)